# SQL Server query help... need to convert varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am writing a query to fetch results for all the values in a column which is of `varchar` type.. are less than '29/08/2010' (date)

My Query:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE COLUMN1 < '29/08/2010'
```

Here the column1 is of `varchar` type. I am using SQL Server 2005

Is there a way to make this possible..??

Pls help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whatever you do, remember to campaign to get the column changed to the datetime data type. It will save immense problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE CONVERT(datetime, COLUMN1, 103) > CONVERT(datetime, '29/08/2010', 103)
```

Comment: Ahh yes - changed it now, and see that it is the same answer as above - Doh :)

Comment: Except that I see that the above example uses 110 (mm-dd-yy) - I would say that it should be 103 (dd/mm/yyyy).

Comment: where is the where and not whhere

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE convert(datetime,COLUMN1,110) <  convert(datetime, '29/08/2010',110)
```

Comment: I got this error... The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

Comment: in column there will be some invalid date will be there

Comment: I checked the data... and i see that all the values are of this format 'dd/mm/yyyy'

Answer (score 1):

```
Convert(field,datetime,101)
```

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Answer (score 0):

If your strictly storing Data data on your COLUMN1, then why is your defined your data type as varchar?

From the performance point of view, It will kill the performance, because Converting Varchar to DateTime or any other will make your indexes inefficient if there is any. Generally using functions like RIGHT() or CONVERT, LIKE'% %' or Like 'a%' will make the WHERE Clause a Non-Sargable, resulting an index scan operation to retrieve the data.

Comment: i am having this column as a dynamic one.. for generating dynamic sql... sometimes i may get values like NAME/EMAIL/CURRENCY/DATE